# Adding buttons dynamically with addView doesn't work

Tags: java, android-layout, view

The code below is part of my program. When I click on the button `sunday`, I want that 4 buttons will be created. However, it crashes in the `addView` part:

```
sunday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        LinearLayout lay (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.lay_schedule);
        Button btnS1 = new Button(getContext());
        Button btnS2 = new Button(getContext());
        Button btnS3 = new Button(getContext());
        Button btnS4 = new Button(getContext());

        btnS1.setText("Add Your Lesson");
        btnS2.setText("Add Your Lesson");
        btnS3.setText("Add Your Lesson");
        btnS4.setText("Add Your Lesson");

        lay.addView(btnS1);
        lay.addView(btnS2);
        lay.addView(btnS3);
        lay.addView(btnS4);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing define your layout in XML and give it an ID,
assume that you have defined LinearLayout in xml and you called it MyLayout

in java code define your LinearLayout as global variable and initialize it under onCreate Method as follow

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
LinearLayout myLinear;
Button myButton;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   myLinear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinear)// as we defined linear layout in xml
myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myBtton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(public void onClick(View v){
this.myLinearLayout.addView(new Button("My text"));}


});
}
```